# How to get (format) a Firebird v3 DATEDIFF() to the number of years, months and days all together?

Tags: firebird

In Firebird 3 I can use `DATEDIFF()` with either `YEAR`, `MONTH` or `DAY` to get the number of years, months **or** days respectively.

I need a way to get all-in-one years, months **and** days.

For example: **412 days** should be represented as **1 year, 1 month and 16 days**.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking something like this:

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime, @y int, @m int, @d int
set @d1 = '2018-10-26'
set @d2 = '2019-12-12'

set @y = datediff(year, @d1, @d2)
set @m = datediff(month, dateadd(year, @y, @d1), @d2) 
if dateadd(month, @m, dateadd(year, @y, @d1)) > @d2 set @m = @m - 1

set @d = datediff(day, dateadd(month, @m, dateadd(year, @y, @d1)), @d2)
print cast(@y as nvarchar) + ' year(s) ' + cast(@m as nvarchar) + ' month(s) and ' + cast(@d as nvarchar) + ' day(s)'
```

Results:

> 1 year(s) 1 month(s) and 16 day(s)

Comment: I don't get this line: `if dateadd(month, @m, dateadd(year, @y, @d1)) > @d2 set @m = @m - 1`.

Comment: That looks like T-SQL which will not work with Firebird

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something better solved in the presentation layer of your application. However, in Firebird 3, you can define a procedural function that does this for you:

```sql
create function period_between(start_date date, end_date date)
  returns varchar(100)
as
declare temp_date date;
declare years smallint;
declare months smallint;
declare days smallint;
begin
    -- swap dates if necessary
    if (start_date > end_date) then
    begin
        temp_date = start_date;
        start_date = end_date;
        end_date = temp_date;
    end

    -- calculate number of years
    years = datediff(year from start_date to end_date);
    temp_date = dateadd(years year to start_date);
    if (temp_date > end_date) then
    begin
        years = years - 1;
        temp_date = dateadd(-1 year to temp_date);
    end

    -- calculate number of months
    months = datediff(month from temp_date to end_date);
    temp_date = dateadd(months month to temp_date);
    if (temp_date > end_date) then
    begin
        months = months - 1;
        temp_date = dateadd(-1 month to temp_date);
    end

    -- calculate number of days
    days = datediff(day from temp_date to end_date);

    return '' || years || ' year(s) ' || months || ' month(s) and ' || days || ' day(s)';
end
```

This is similar to the solution by CR241, except it is in Firebird syntax, and it uses local variables for intermediate values.

You can call this function like:

```sql
select period_between(date'2018-10-26', date'2019-12-12') from rdb$database
```